# vim hangs when I open a typescript file

Tags: syntax-highlighting, plugin-system

I have a vim 8.2 on a Gentoo Linux running on a more or less 8 years old PC.

I almost never have a performance issue with vim, unless you open a one-line huge xml
oder json file, but those are vary rare cases.

My team has started using typescript and so many of our javascript files have
been transformed to ts. I use `vim-plug` for plugging management and I added the
[HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim](https://github.com/HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim) plugin.

However if I open a typescript file, even smaller ones, vim starts normally but
after a few seconds it gets very unresponsive, if I scroll down the syntax
highlight is also gone and eventually vim hangs. Looking at the process with
`htop` I can see that the process is constantly running at 100% CPU. The only
thing I can do is a `kill -9`.

Vim `8.2` (or at least the Gentoo version) has support for typescript in the
default installation, looking at the files in `/usr/share/vim/vim82` the
provided files seems to be the same as the ones from the `yats` plugin.

So to be sure that I don't have other plugins interfering, I made a backup of my
vim config and remove it from my HOME directory.

The `yats` github page says to explitly set `set re=1`, so I created a new
`~/.vimrc` file and added this line to it. When I open the typescript file, I
get the same result, so my other plugins didn't affect it at all.

So the `set re=1` made me curious and if I set it instead to 2 or 0 (the
default), then opening the same typescript file does not lead vim to hang.

So, did I understand the warning on the github page correctly and I should add
`set re=1`? If so, why is it worse for me?

How can you check what exactly in a plugin is making vim go crazy?

In case this is somehow important:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Apr  4 2020 16:30:54)
Included patches: 1-360
Modified by Gentoo-8.2.0360
Compiled by shaoran@gallifrey
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
+arabic            +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autochdir         +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_lang        -terminal
-balloon_eval      -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
-browse            +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
+byte_offset       +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+channel           +insert_expand     -perl              +title
+cindent           +job               +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+clientserver      +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+clipboard         +keymap            +postscript        +vartabs
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_info      +libcall           -python            +visual
+comments          +linebreak         +python3           +visualextra
+conceal           +lispindent        +quickfix          +viminfo
+cryptv            +listcmds          +reltime           +vreplace
-cscope            +localmap          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cursorbind        -lua               +ruby              +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +scrollbind        +windows
+dialog_con        +mksession         +signs             +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      +smartindent       +X11
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             +xfontset
-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+emacs_tags        +mouse_gpm         +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary        
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vim/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -O2 -pipe -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc   -L. -Wl,-O1 -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-O1 -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim    -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lelf -lnsl   -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm  -lruby24 -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

[My vim configuration](https://github.com/shaoran/vimrc)

Answer (score 17):

tldr; Add `set re=2` into .vimrc prevents the issue on mac. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Welcome! It would be great if you could explain why this works for you.

Comment: Echoing Biggybi's sentiments, welcome to [vi.se]! Please consider taking a few minutes to complete the [tour]. Given that OP already mentions that `re=2` works, I'm not sure this truly qualifies as an answer to the question "should I use `re=1` and why is it worse than alternatives?"

Comment: Environment:    MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018)   iTerm,  and the .vimrc only one line: `syntax enable`.     open a typescript file, like: https://github.com/codex-team/editor.js/blob/next/src/codex.ts  and press Control+f  and Control+b, the screen is hangs.  add `set re=1`, same the hangs.  change to `set re=2`, ok~

Comment: I don't know the reason, but it is true.

Comment: Sad that people downvoted you when this does in fact resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm on OSX Vi 8.2. If I put `set re=2` in my `~/.vimrc` or modeline then everything is kosher. However, if I put it in my `~/.vim/ftplugin/typescript.vim` file then it still hangs for me. Seems like a weird difference to me but that's what I"m experiencing. To confirm, if I turn `syntax off` it never hangs.  I had to explicitly set `set re=0` in `~/.vimrc` to keep it flexible and set `setlocal re=2` in ftplugin file.

Comment: Belleza! Belleza!

Comment: 2019 MBP on Ventura, running vim in iTerm2, and `set re=2` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 11):

From `:help 're'`:

```
                        *'regexpengine'* *'re'*
'regexpengine' 're' number  (default 0)
            global
    This selects the default regexp engine. |two-engines|
    The possible values are:
        0   automatic selection
        1   old engine
        2   NFA engine
    Note that when using the NFA engine and the pattern contains something
    that is not supported the pattern will not match.  This is only useful
    for debugging the regexp engine.
    Using automatic selection enables Vim to switch the engine, if the
    default engine becomes too costly.  E.g., when the NFA engine uses too
    many states.  This should prevent Vim from hanging on a combination of
    a complex pattern with long text.
```

This "old" engine supports everything but uses backtracking (which can be very slow in some patterns). The new engine is NFA-based, and may be slower or faster depending on the pattern. See `:help two-engines`. You can actually force a given pattern to use a different engine with the atom `\%#=0` (or 1 or 2).

The best seems to be the default (0) which allows vim to decide.

You should probably talk to the yats people about why they "need" `regexpengine=1`...

Comment: Yeah, I read the documentation as well, but in my case the opposite happened, with `re=1` the whole process hangs. I think I'll post an issue there.

Comment: I think the root of the problem is the use of the `\K\k*` pattern in _/usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/typescriptcommon.vim_.

In the [vim doc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_27.html) `\K` and `\k` are keyword matches, but they are backreferences in the [perl doc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre). Adding `set regexpengine=0` to _~/.vimrc_ worked for me.